# How to search map address in custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, search

I built a custom post type "shop" with [Custom Post Type UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) plugin and added a field "address" (Google Map type) with [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin.

From the response of `WP_Query('post_type=shop');`, I got the following:

```
$shop = WP_Query('post_type=shop');
while($shop->have_post()) {
  $shop->the_post();
  $location = get_field('map-location');
  if($location != null) {
    echo $location['address'];
  }
}
```

Here I got a list of addresses. How do I search with this "address"? Let's say user wants to search shop that is in "London", how can I achieve this?

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE**

Sample result of searching "15":

- 筲箕灣東大街15號B地下
- 九龍觀塘偉業街103號振邦工業大廈地鋪
- 九龍土瓜灣旭日街一號 瑞英工業大廈第一期A座地下

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [`meta_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'shop',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'map-location',
            'value' => 'London',
            'compare' => 'LIKE' // the = operator might work depending on how your data is stored
        ),
    )
);
```

Note: I am making some assumptions about how ACF stores data.

Comment: Thanks! Tried and it works. However, when the value is "15", it returns some addresses that does not include 15.

Comment: I can't answer that without seeing the data. The `LIKE` operator may be too broad. You should use `=` if possible.

Comment: Updated sample result in question (sorry, it's in Chinese).

Comment: You've probably got an encoding/collation issue with the database. That is not something I have a lot of experience with.

Comment: I might find the reason behind. When I look into DB's `meta_value` of that address, it really contains "15" in the coordinates (which are the other fields in the same post type). Value of `meta_value` is: `a:3:{s:7:"address";s:51:"九龍觀塘偉業街103號振邦工業大廈地鋪";s:3:"lat";s:9:"22.315908";s:3:"lng";s:18:"114.21533390000002";}`. **Question:** how can I search the address only?

Comment: Ok. Now I can answer. What you have are serialized strings. MySQL can't parse those. You can't really search data that is stored that way. In short, it is a ridiculous way to store data.

Comment: See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/87268/21376

Comment: And: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/140436/21376

Comment: Okay. I will query for `post_type` first, then search the address in PHP. Thanks again.

Comment: And: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/82585/21376

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expression `RLIKE`:

```
$val = '15';
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'shop',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'map-location',
            'value' => 's:7:"address";s:[0-9]+:"[^"]*' . preg_quote( $val ) . '[^"]*";',
            'compare' => 'RLIKE'
        ),
    )
);
```

although it can fail if your address data contains a double quote. If you always have a `lat` and a `lng` field following the `address` then you could extend the expression to match these and do away with the need for the `[^"]` bits (replacing them with dots).

Comment: Oh, I don't even know it's able to use RegEx. Nice answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use meta query to search for a particular field text.

```
 $val = 'London';
 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'shop',
   'meta_query' => array(
     array(
        'key' => 'map-location',
        'value' => $val,
        'compare' => 'LIKE' 
     ),
   )
 );
 $query = new WP_Query($arg);
```

[Class Reference/WP Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

Comment: This is virtually identical to my answer. What additional information do you think it provides?